# Bash getopts: recognizing negative options (-x- or +x)?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopts

(Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18134669/2877364), but in bash.)

I have an existing bash script that uses the builtin getopts to recognize `-s` (flag only - no argument).  I find I use that option every time, so I would like to make it default *unless* `-s-` or `+s` is specified on the command line.  However, although [ksh `getopts` can handle `+s`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/getopts.htm), I can't find that capability in the [bash `getopts` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

My current workarounds are:

1. to use `s:` so I can recognize `-s-` by `$OPTARG`=`"-"`; or
2. to replace `-s` with a different option, e.g., `-d` (for "don't").

However, #1 has the problem that it swallows the next argument if I accidentally specify `-s`, and #2 has the problem that it uses a different switch letter than the one I already have in my muscle memory.  I am hoping there might be a straightforward way to parse `-s-` or `+s` in bash.

- The [util-linux getopt(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html) also doesn't appear to have `+s`.  It can handle optional arguments, so might be able to take `-s-`.  However, I've not used `getopt(1)` before so would appreciate pointers on how not to shoot myself in the foot.
- [BashFAQ 035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) says "parse it yourself."  if you have a routine already written that does `+s` or `-s-`, I'd love to see it.

My current arg-parsing loop is very basic:

```
while getopts "nthps" opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
        <other cases cut>
        (s)     saw_s="yes"
                ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of negative flags (`+abcdef +g`) differs from a normal sequence (`-abcdef -g`) with just the plus character. So you can simply revert the flag value for `+` prefix.

The second form of negative sequence is as simple. Just strip the last character (`-`), and negate the normal flag value.

**Example**

The following script accepts all of the mentioned formats, e.g. `-ns -n -s -n- -ns- +ns +n +s`.

```
arglist='ns'

while (( $# )); do
  arg="$1"

  # Parse -abcdef- (negative form of -abcdef) options
  if [ "${arg:0:1}" = '-' -a "${arg#${arg%?}}" = '-' ]; then
    flag_val=no
    arg="${arg%?}" # -abcdef- becomes -abcdef
  elif [ "${arg:0:1}" = '+' ]; then
    flag_val=no
    arg="${arg/#+/-}"
  else
    flag_val=yes
  fi

  # OPTIND is the index of the next argument to be processed.
  # We are going to parse "$arg" from the beginning, so we need
  # to reset it to 1 before calling getopts.
  OPTIND=1

  while getopts "$arglist" opt "$arg"; do
    case "$opt" in
      s) saw_s="$flag_val" ;;
      n) saw_n="$flag_val" ;;
    esac
  done

  shift
done

# Set default values
: ${saw_s:=yes}
: ${saw_n:=no}

printf "saw_s='%s'\nsaw_n='%s'\n" "$saw_s" "$saw_n"
```

*Testing*

```
$ ./pargs.sh
saw_s='yes'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -s
saw_s='yes'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh +s
saw_s='no'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -s-
saw_s='no'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -s- +s -s
saw_s='yes'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -s +s
saw_s='no'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh +s -s
saw_s='yes'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -s -s-
saw_s='no'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -sn
saw_s='yes'
saw_n='yes'
$ ./pargs.sh -sn -s-
saw_s='no'
saw_n='yes'
$ ./pargs.sh -sn +s
saw_s='no'
saw_n='yes'
$ ./pargs.sh +sn
saw_s='no'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -sn-
saw_s='no'
saw_n='no'
$ ./pargs.sh -sn- -n
saw_s='no'
saw_n='yes'
```